# Null Pointer Exception on getObjectValue() using mockito

Tags: java, mockito

**Code Snippet**

```
private AttributeCache attributeCache;
attributeCache = mock(AttributeCache.class);
ServiceAttribute serviceAttribute = new ServiceAttribute();
String serviceAttrId = "M";
when(attributeCache.get(serviceAttrId).getObjectValue()).thenReturn(serviceAttribute);
```

When method throwing **Null pointer exception** due to getObjectValue(), when I remove getObjectValue, it gave me an error that change type of serviceAttribute to Element?

any update! How we can use mockito with respect to above scenerio?

in normal scenario we cast the object as follow

```
serviceAttribute = (ServiceAttribute) (attributeCache.get(serviceAttrId).getObjectValue());
```

Comment: Methods of mocks return `null` by default (for reference types other than the numeric types).

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is in calling `attributeCache.get(serviceAttrId).getObjectValue()` in your attempt to mock; the part `attributeCache.get(serviceAttrId)` will return `null` which gives you the `NullPointerException`. A solution would be something like this:

```
private AttributeCache attributeCache;
attributeCache = mock(AttributeCache.class);
ServiceAttribute serviceAttribute = new ServiceAttribute();
Attribute attribute = mock(Attribute.class);
when(attributeCache.get(Matchers.any(String.class)).thenReturn(attribute);
String serviceAttrId = "M";
when(attribute.getObjectValue()).thenReturn(serviceAttribute);
```

This is assuming that `attributeCache.get(...)` returns something of the type `Attribute`; you'll have to replace it with the actual type of course.

---

**EDIT:** I've tried to reproduce the error you get in the changed version without any success. Here's my version:

```
package com.stackoverflow.shahid.ghafoor;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class MockStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new MockStuff().run();
            System.out.println("Everything's fine");
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Caught an error:");
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public MockStuff() {
    }

    public void run() {
            AttributeCache attributeCache;
        attributeCache = mock(AttributeCache.class);
            ServiceAttribute serviceAttribute = new ServiceAttribute();
        Attribute attribute = mock(Attribute.class);
            when(attributeCache.get(any(String.class))).thenReturn(attribute);
        String serviceAttrId = "M";
            when(attribute.getObjectValue()).thenReturn(serviceAttribute);
    }

    private class AttributeCache {
        Attribute get(String something) {
            return null;
            }
    }

    private class Attribute {
        ServiceAttribute getObjectValue() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class ServiceAttribute {

    }
}
```

It is of course possible, that you've run into a limitation of Mockito here; if so switching from

```
Mockito.when(attribute.getObjectValue()).thenReturn(serviceAttribute)
```

to

```
Mockito.doReturn(serviceAttribute).when(attribute).getObjectValue()
```

might help, depending on what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for reply! now again exception in this line `when(attribute.getObjectValue()).thenReturn(serviceAttribute);`

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor What kind of exception are you getting?

Comment: this one `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);`

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor Please update your question to include the changed code and new Exception; right now I'm guessing at what may be wrong. Generally speaking however there is a problem with what you're trying to mock there.

Comment: the code snippet, you put in answer is identical to my code. :)

Comment: let me share you get object method `public final Object getObjectValue() {
        return value;
    }`

Comment: @ blalasaadri Actually, I think this is issue in mockito, because `inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.
   It is a limitation of the mock engine.`

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor It's possible. Check my update, maybe there's something helpful in there.